# Error: package 'gmapping' not found

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the gmapping package, but why I get this error when

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=front_laser _odom_frame:=odom
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276652/error:-package-%27gmapping%27-not-found/) by [Yunlong](https://answers.ros.org/users/32751/yunlong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-25**:
*How* have you installed it? From source, a package manager (e.g., `apt`), or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May running the command below the package will be found:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rospack profile
```

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0